# Is there a pythonic way to use a Counter as Key when updating a dictionary with new elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary than needs to be updated with new elements over time, and I want that the key is a counter that increases by 1 for each new element added.

My solution looks like this:

```
dic = {}
counter = 0

def add_to_dic(dic, element):
    global counter
    if element not in dic.values():
       counter += 1
       dic[counter] = element

element = "something_same"
add_to_dic(dic, element)
element = "something_same"
add_to_dic(dic, element)
element = "something_same"
add_to_dic(dic, element)
element = "something_different"
add_to_dic(dic, element)
 
print(dic)

# $ {1: 'something_same', 2: 'something_different'}
```

Is there a better way of doing this incrementation of the key?

#------------------------------ Update ------------------------------#

In my scenario I have multiple rpi/clients that connect to a Flask server and they send video frames via POST requests.

```
response  = requests.post(server_url, data = client_ip + frame, headers=headers, timeout=1/20)
```

In the server I want to dynamically allocate a key to each of these clients, based on their ip address. So if a client connect and starts sending frames, a new dictionary key is created for each individual client. I am sending the ip as a string appended to the start of the frames. IP range "192.168.1.100" and up, so len of string is 13.  *frame_to_stream* is the dictionary that I use to keep the frames of the clients and *client_dic* is the dictionary I want for the counter_key--ip_client combination.

```
#...
frame_to_stream = {}
client_dic = {}

@flask.route('/api/test', methods=['POST'])      
    def test():
        r                         = request    
        client_ip                 = r.data[:13]
        if client_ip not in client_dic.values():
            counter += 1
        client_dic[counter] = client_ip
        frame_to_stream[counter] = r.data[13:] #Frame of that client
        #...
```

After that, I just use the Key to put in the URL so I can decide which video stream I want to see.

```
@flask.route("/video_feed")
    def video_feed():       
        cam_id = request.args.get("cam_id")
        if frame_to_stream.get(int(cam_id)) == None:
            print (f"Camera-ID={cam_id} not Connected")
            return f"Camera-ID={cam_id} not Connected"
        return Response( gen_function(int(cam_id)), mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=jpgboundary" ) 

#Open in browser: localhost:5000/video_feed?cam_id=1
```

The generator function used for streaming is:

```
def gen(cam_id):                                                     
    header = "--jpgboundary\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
    prefix = ""
    while True:
        frame = frame_to_stream[cam_id]
        frame = analyze_and_modify_frame( frame )    
        msg = (prefix + header + "Content-Length: {}\r\n\r\n".format(len(frame))  )
        yield (msg.encode("utf-8") + frame)
        prefix = "\r\n"
        time.sleep(1/30)
```

Comment: if you're just using a sequential counter as the key, why not use a list?

Comment: Are you ever removing elements, but still needing to maintain the old numbering?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever access the dict by the key, but frequently access the dict by value. are you sure the key and value shouldn't be swapped? Searching the whole dict values every time you update it will get slow for large dicts.

Comment: i updated the post to make it more understandable. @MarkMeyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not significantly different, but you can use `itertools.count` to be your source of new keys.

```
from itertools import count

counter = count()

def add_to_dic(dic, element): 
    if element not in dic.values():
        dic[next(counter)] = element
```

With an instance of `count`, `next` is essentially the equivalent of `counter++`: you get the pending value, and set the next larger value as the next pending value. Since you aren't assigning to `counter`, you can also drop the `global` statement.

By default, the sequence starts at 0. You can pass a different starting value (such as 1) as an argument to `count`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, this is equivalent to using a list, if you are OK with the keys starting at 0 and removing an item shouldn't leave a gap in the sequence of keys.

```
d = []
def add_to_dic(dic, element):
    if element not in dic:
        d.append(element)
```